# retrieving all true booleanfields in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

suppose my models.py looks like

```
class Internal_Product_Enabled_Feature(models.Model):
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    show_performance_test_results = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_continuous_integration_test_results = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_iteration_wise_test_results = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_test_case_documentation = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_common_java_docs = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_product_javadocs = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_product_perldocs = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_bug_reports = models.BooleanField(null=False)
    show_code_coverage_reports = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

from this model class i want to extract only those fiels which are true in django template.
i really dont know how o apply filter or extract that data in template.
i tried below code which is not working

```
<div class="drop PRODUCTS">
                {%for p in products%}
                {% if p.product_id.type == 'p' %}                   

                    <div class="drop-col">                          
                            <h3 class="pane-title">{{p.product_id.name}}</h3>
                            <div class="pane-content">                                  
                                    <ul class="menu">
                                        {{if p.show_performance_test_results == 1}}
                                        <li><a href="#">show_performance_test_result</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Bug Reports</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Code Coverage</a></li>  
                                        {%endif%}
                                    </ul>                                   
                            </div>                          
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
```

Comment: `{{if p.show_performance_test_results == 1}}` — you've used `{{}}` instead of `{%%}`. Also you don't need a comparison, a simple `{% if p.show_performance_test_results %}` should be enough. Without defining what you mean by "not working" it's hard to pinpoint more problems with your code without spending too much effort to reproduce it locally.

Comment: ok..thnx for the correction..but i want to extract all the true values in a single filter. and i dont know how to do it..any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You want to filter only objects that have _any_ of the `show_*` fields set?

Comment: How are you populating the products context variable in the view? That's where you should do the filtering.